# Is there a generic Java SCM API that work with different repositories?

Tags: java, git, svn, version-control, mercurial

There is a Java API for any popular Source Code Management (SCM) like SvnKit or JGit. But is there an open source API on top of this that support multiple systems?

Answer (score 1):

IDEs and build tools usually define an API for their SCMs plugins:

- Eclipse: [Team Support API](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/team.htm)
- Jenkins: [SCM-Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/scm-api-plugin)
- Crucible: [SCM Plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/FECRUDEV/Crucible+SCM+Plugin+Tutorial)

But I would expect that these plugins are deeply integrated into their tooling environment, i.e. not easy to use as standalone library.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sonarQube and scm activity plugin for the sonar it support most of the repositories.

Comment: This providers seems few dependency but it supports only the blame command.